# how to use svg inside div tag

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I wish to use svg element inside a div tag, the idea is when i make the div layer invisible than all of the svg elements in the div would be invisible. below is the  part of the declaration code, but m struggling to know how to use my created svg variable inside the div . any comments please.

```
var svgwidth=1800;
var svgheight=700;
 var vis = mysvg=d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", svgwidth)
  .attr("height", svgheight).style("border", "1px solid black");

 mydiv = d3.select("body").append("div").style("position", "absolute")
.style("font", "16px sans-serif").style("background", "lightsteelblue")
.style("border", "1px black solid")
.style("border-radius", "8px")
.style("opacity", "0.7")
 .style("visibility", "visible");
  mydiv.style("top", (20)+"px").style("left",(20)+"px")
  .style("height",60+"px")
     .style("width",60+"px");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order to

```
mydiv = d3.select("body").append("div"). ...
```

and then

```
vis = mysvg = mydiv.append("svg") ...
```

Comment: actually i wish to create many div layers  for my page, each div would be using  d3 svg, so if i follow the above order than i have to append svg again and again is it right. and does it matter to include several svg elements.

Comment: append all svg to this div `vis = mysvg = mydiv.append("svg")`, `vis1 = mysvg1 = mydiv.append("svg")`, so when you will make div invisable, all svg become invisible too